# Which airfoil is used on the Boeing 737 NG vertical stabilizer/rudder?

Tags: boeing-737, airfoil, rudder, vertical-stabilizer

Does anyone know what airfoil Boeing uses on it's 737 NG's vertical stabilizer or the rudder itself? I can't seem to find the info anywhere and I need it for a university project.

Comment: Most probably is a proprietary airfoil but for your project a NACA 0009 or 0012 will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by a professor in my university, the vertical stabilizer of the 737 uses either a NACA0012 or an exclusive airfoil designed by Boeing. Most probably, it is a variation of the NACA0012 created by them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).